# Android don't play sound effect when Do not Disturb is on

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, silent, android-sound

I'm using the MediaPlayer to play a sound effect.
However when DnD (Do not Disturb) is turned on it still plays the sound.

This is my code:

```
public static void playSound(Context context, @RawRes int soundId)
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundId);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer -> {
        mp.release();
    });
}
```

I tried setting the audio stream type like this, but then my sound won't play at all:

> mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

How to initialize the media player so my sound does the following:

- DnD off: play
- DnD Total silence: don't play
- DnD Alarms only: don't play
- DnD Priority only: don't play

Currently the sound is only silenced when DnD is in Total silence mode.

The only thing I can think of now is to retrieve the DnD setting and only play the sound if it's off. But that seems more like a work-around to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the status of the `Do not disturb` mode first like this

```
 try {
        Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "zen_mode"); // this return an int
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That statement returns an int value that you can work with like this

- 0 - If DnD is off.
- 1 - If DnD is on - Priority Only
- 2 - If DnD is on - Total Silence
- 3 - If DnD is on - Alarms Only

Now all you have to do is a simple `if` statement and you play or stop you audio accordingly.

You can stop the `MediaPlayer` like this

```
mp.stop();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that this is possible, but like I mentioned in my question is that it feels like a work-around. Isn't there a way I can play sounds for a certain priority that will automatically get silenced when DnD is on?

Comment: For this `will automatically get silenced when DnD is on` you can create a `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen for the DnD status and act accordingly.